# Session value lost

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am making a session in a controller and assigning it a value. But the problem is when ever I get the value of the session in the other function, I cannot retrieve that value.
I have autoload the library of the session.

Here is my code:

```
public function Authenticate_User()
    {$this->session->set_userdata('end_user', base64_encode($User_Credentials[0]));
//              $_SESSION['end_user'] = base64_encode($User_Credentials[0]);
                echo 'session value : ' . print_r($this->session->all_userdata(), true) . '<br />';
                echo 'authorized';
}


public function Logout()
    {

        echo 'logout value : ' . $this->session->userdata("end_user") . '<br />';

        echo 'unsetted';
    }
```

in logout function, I cannot retrieve the value of the session in function. I need some assistance?

Comment: can you share your session config values? are you using database sessions?

Comment: $config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

Comment: Can you post the error that is displayed in the browser?

Comment: I dont get any error. When ever I get the session variable value from the next function after setting it, the session ID gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

Change this config values

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
```

to:

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
```

Edit
You can try this:

app folder > application > config

```
$config['sess_driver']                        = 'native';
```

Comment: I dont want to use database in order to create session, is there anyway I can create the sessions the same way like native PHP ?